# MySQL Group By up to certain string character

Tags: mysql, group-by

I am currently working on a project where I have several string that may start with different message but somewhere in the string will contain a :.

For example the field may include

> Unknown username/password attempted to login. User: admin Failed to
>
> add user account. MySQL Error: certain my sql error Unknown
>
> username/password attempted to login. User: administrator

Basically I want to group the fields together up to the : sign e.g. Unknown username/password attempted to login. User: would be grouped as 1 entry.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this...

```
SELECT msg1,wholemsg FROM 
 (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(message, ':', 1) AS msg1, message as wholemsg FROM <your table>
  WHERE <your condition>)
GROUP BY msg1
```

Comment: Thanks this worked great, is there a way I can put a count in as well using the MySQL COUNT() so I can display a count for how many times the msg1 i.e. the part message before the : occurs in the database

Comment: yep... SELECT msg1,COUNT(wholemsg) as msgCount..    Please mark as answer if you got the correct answer :)